# While inserting the text checkpoint for time by clicking on it(say 12:50 pm) and running it,its giving the result as failed?

Tags: testing, build-automation, qtp

It does give the result as passed when i click on it and give ok to run test, But when i gave the value for it as (1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm) and checked regular expression and saved it. while running it the test is getting failed.(I tried it on worldtimeserver.com)
The expression for that is

Browser("Current local time in").Page("Current local time in").Check CheckPoint("Current   local time in India")

> Its not showing the time i selected instead it showing like "the check that is selected between is and monday ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression looks to be invalid for time. Use the Regular Expression Evaluator tool in the checkpoint to validate the RegEx.

1. From the Object Repository, select the checkpoint.
2. To the right of the "Constant", click the "Constant Value Options" button.
3. Click the "Right Arrow" button to the right of the "Value".
4. From the drop down list, click "Open Regular Expression Evaluator...".
5. Use the tool the evaluate your regular expression.

Comment: I used that evaluator and then i tried but again its getting failed.

Comment: More details with specifics would be helpful.